# Поставить like в facebook, используя open graph

Tags: ios, соцсети, facebook-api

Нужно поставить лайк для поста facebook. (приложение для iOS). SDK не использую.
вот вроде для этого есть ссылка
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes

```
curl -X POST \   -F
'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \  
-F 'object=OG_OBJECT_URL' \   https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB
ID]/og.likes
```

передаю POST- ом access_token и object(ссылку like, вложенную в полученном посте)
на адрес https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes, где [User FB ID] - id владельца поста.

в ответ мне приходит

```
{
error =     {
    code = 240;
    message = "(#240) Requires a valid user to be specified (either via
    the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.";
    type = OAuthException;
}; }
```

Кто нибудь знает, как мне решить проблему? Как правильно "лайкнуть" пост?